# How to sort two different core data objects?

Tags: ios, core-data, entity, combinations, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have two core data entities. Say **Birthday** & **Anniversary**.

Attributes of these entities are,

**Birthday** - Name, Age, Birth date

**Anniversary** - Name, Anniversary date

Showing each entity separately in a tableview can be done with fetched results controller. Thats fine!! But, I want to show a tableview that combines both birthdays and anniversary days. The sorting should be done by taking "Birth date" from **Birthday** & "Anniversary date" from **Anniversary** entity.

**Questions**:

- Should I use two fetchedresultscontroller to fetch objects from these two entities? And then should I sort those objects? This is fine with minimal objects, but it takes more processing time when the count increases.
- Should I create a common parent table, that posses "Birth date" and "Anniversary date" values? If so, how can I fetch  & how can I define sort descriptor?

I'm really new to core data and dont have any idea about this scenario. Giving examples would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're best bet might be to use two `fetchedresultscontrollers`, then sort each set of results within each other, then merge the two. That seems like a logical way to accomplish this...Another idea might be to have a common model between Birthday and Anniversary that shares as many properties as possible (IE name and date), and then you're sort descriptor could work on the model super class' date property.

Answer (score 0):

Add a parent entity. Both anniversary and birthday should inherit common properties. Then You can use one frc to query both anniversary and birthday.